# .NET Core passing view @foreach list to controller as array parm

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In my view I have a list of values displayed for update from my model...

```
@foreach (var key in item.keys)
{
    <tr class="table table-hover table-responsive-sm display" ; style="color:white;">
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => key.keyName, new { @type = "text", maxlength = "50", required = "yes" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => key.dataLength, new { @type = "number", min=1, max=32000, required = "yes" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => key.dataDecLength, new { @type = "number", min=0, max=15, required = "yes" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => key.rpgDataType, new { @type = "text", maxlength = "7", required = "yes" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => key.sqlDataType, new { @type = "text", maxlength = "7", required = "yes" })</td>
    </tr>
}
```

On a button click and submit, I want to pass a few standalone string values and then this entire item.keys to my homecontroller procedure... but how?

I have tried both...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm
```

and

```
<a button class="btn btn-info form-control text-white" typeof="button" onclick="location.href
```

but neither seem to work.

Am I using them incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Update

Your problem may come from the namespace. I have posted the entire file so that you can see what's wrong.
This will work with async Task correctly. And htmlhelper or ajax, each will work and only one is needed, choose one and the other can be deleted.

---

Update

Since you want to pass a model with several properties and an array, I think my previous code is not exactly correct. I have updated my answer with both htmlhelper and ajax way, please check if it work with you.

> Model Sample

```
namespace YourNamespace.Models
{
    public class Sample
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public Key[]? Keys { get; set; } = new Key[] { }; //here is the array
    }
}
```

> Model Key

```
namespace YourNamespace.Models
{
    public class Key
    {
             public int id { get; set; }
             public string keyName { get; set; }
             public int dataLength { get; set; }
             public int dataDecLength { get; set; }
             public string rpgDataType { get; set; }
             public string sqlDataType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> My Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using YourNamespace.Data;
using YourNamespace.Models;
namespace YourNamespace.Controllers
{
    public class KeysController : Controller
    {
        private readonly NewDemoContext _context;

        public KeysController(NewDemoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        //Your controller to pass the model to view
        ...

        //Test for htmlhelper
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PassTest([FromForm]Sample sample)
        {
            return View(sample);
        }

        //Test for ajax, remember to add [frombody] attribute to bind the model from post
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PassTest2([FromBody]Sample sample)
        {
            return View(sample);
        }
    }
}
```

> My View

```
//I have passed an entire model to this view
//This part for htmlhelper
@model YourNamespace.Models.Sample

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "TestIndex";
}

<h1>TestIndex</h1>

<table style="overflow-y:scroll">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th class="sorting_asc text-center">Model Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("PassTest", "Keys", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "number", @min = 0} })
                    <br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text"} })
                    <br />
                    <br />

                    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Keys.Length; i++)
                    {
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Keys[i].id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "number", @min = 0} })
                        <br />
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Keys[i].sqlDataType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text"} })
                        <br />
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Keys[i].rpgDataType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text"} })
                        <br />
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Keys[i].dataDecLength, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "number", @min = 0} })
                        <br />
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Keys[i].dataLength, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "number", @min = 0} })
                        <br />
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Keys[i].keyName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text"} })
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    }
                    <br />
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>

//This part for ajax
<div class="" id="101">
    <div class="text-center" id="m-id" value="@Model.Id">@Model.Id</div>
    <br />
    <div class="text-center" id="m-name" value="@Model.Name">@Model.Name</div>
    <br />
    <br />

    @for (var i = 0; i < @Model.Keys.Length; i++)
    {
        <div class="text-center" id="m-key-id" value="@Model.Keys[i].id">@Model.Keys[i].id</div>
        <br />
        <div class="text-center" id="m-key-sqlDataType" value="@Model.Keys[i].sqlDataType">@Model.Keys[i].sqlDataType</div>
        <br />
        <div class="text-center" id="m-key-rpgDataType" value="@Model.Keys[i].rpgDataType">@Model.Keys[i].rpgDataType</div>
        <br />
        <div class="text-center" id="m-key-dataDecLength" value="@Model.Keys[i].dataDecLength">@Model.Keys[i].dataDecLength</div>
        <br />
        <div class="text-center" id="m-key-dataLength" value="@Model.Keys[i].dataLength">@Model.Keys[i].dataLength</div>
        <br />
        <br />
    }
    <br />
    <input class="btn btn-primary" id ="btsave" type="submit" value="Submit2" />
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btsave").on("click", function (sample) {
            var newid = '@Model.Id';
            var newname = '@Model.Name';
            var newkeys = [
                @foreach (var item in Model.Keys)
                {
                    @: { id: @item.id, dataLength: @item.dataLength, dataDecLength: @item.dataDecLength, rpgDataType: '@item.rpgDataType', sqlDataType: '@item.sqlDataType' } ,
                }
            ];

            var newsample = {
                Name: newname,
                Id: newid,
                Keys: newkeys
            };

            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("PassTest2","Keys")',
                data: JSON.stringify(newsample),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.Result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    
                }
            });
        });
    })

</script>
```

Test

> 1.Click on submit and see the value passed with htmlhelper

[image]
[image]

> 2.Click on submit2 and see the value passed with ajax

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks - based on what you provided I have my view coded correctly and my controller method parms as well (I think)... I got an error though on namespace Key and changed it to ConsoleKey - is that ok?  If not, what should it be changed to?

Comment: Could you share the project name, the file which is wrong(located through the error list) and the error message so that we can troubleshoot the error.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I know how to do that... but everything is coded just like your example.. no more errors... but when it runs in debug, there is nothing in key

Comment: is the validateAnitForgeryToken required?

Comment: I update the answer, you can check what is omitted in your project.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and have gone a totally different direction.  I have chosen to use JavaScript in the view with ajax to pass the info.  I have 4 stand alone string variables I want to pass to my controller and then finally this array!  but having trouble passing that array.  I declare my function and do var's for all my strings referencing the model to populate them... then pass them individually on the data portion of the ajax... but not sure how to handle this array that exists in the model (which btw, is defined like public Keys[] keys {get; set; }

Comment: are you able to help me with this direction?

Comment: you added a line of code "set in your context"  where does this code go?  model or controller?

Comment: awesome so got it to work but it is only returning 1 array entry.  btw, my model has a List[] array that these data elements sit in so I just code... Model.list[0].keys... seems to be working regardless but any reason only 1 array element returned?

Comment: ok thank you - i have your first example with htmHelper coded with no issues (I don't have the script in my view as I'm not using that aJax method... but when the sample is returned to the controller it is null.  Your view code copied perfectly no issues... so what did I miss?  I don't need the Ajax with the htmHelper method right?

Comment: plus my controller method must be public async Task<IActtionResult> because I am calling an http webservice to pass this data to a server.  Will it work with this?

Comment: also... the [FromForm]Sample sample) in my controller has issues - the Sample is red underlined - only way to make it go away is to install the Amazon.DeviceFarm.Model

Comment: I updated the answer. Check if it works.

Comment: thanks but NewDemoContext cannot be referenced

Comment: That is the context file generated for scaffold and named by yourself, you can refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-movie-pages